# Python Launcher crashes when code is run through canopy

Tags: python, enthought

I am trying to produce a 2D graph in Python. If I run the code through Terminal on my Mac, the Python Launcher opens and the expected graph is produced.

However when I run the same code in Canopy, the Python Launcher attempts to open before invariably crashing. I get this error message:

> The kernel (user Python environment) has terminated with error code -15. This may be due to a bug in your code or in the kernel itself.

Output captured from the kernel process is shown below.

```
[IPKernelApp] To connect another client to this kernel, use:
[IPKernelApp] --existing /var/folders/cd/w1g2my4x2pz09htx_0svwlhc0000gn/T/tmpvMYt6Y.json"
```

Please advise me what to do so that I can run the code through Canopy and have the Python Launcher produce a graph.

Comment: have you contacted Enthought tech support? Does it crash just with this file, or with any Python script, with or without `matplotlib`/`pyplot`?

Comment: Whenever matplotlib/pyplot is in the code I get an error message in canopy, though not when I run it through terminal. This error message states "%run "/var/folders/cd/w1g2my4x2pz09htx_0svwlhc0000gn/T/tmp681vai.py"